# In the synthesis of azo compounds, given the strongly basic reaction conditions, why is the azo product favoured?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I was reading about the chemical synthesis of aromatic azo compounds, wherein, first a diazo cation is formed from an aromatic primary amine:
$$\ce{Ar–NH2 + NaNO2 + 2HCl -> Ar–N=N+Cl– + 2H2O + NaCl}$$

This cation is subsequently reacted with a phenol under strongly alkaline conditions. EAS takes place with the diazo cation as the electrophile and we get the azo compound at ortho and para positions.

What I was wondering is, since $\ce{OH-}$ is strongly nucleophilic as well (in fact, I would guess more so than ortho and para positions of the phenol anion since the electron density is being distributed via resonance), how is a favourable yield of the product we want obtained in reactions in like this? Also, why would the the ortho and para product be preferred over the cation reaction with the $\ce{O-}$ of the phenol anion?

Comment: It's not done "strongly alkaline conditions". That would lead to deactivation of diazo.

Comment: @Mithoron A pH of 10 is fairly alkaline I'd say

Comment: Maybe "fairly" but not strongly. You could drink a solution with such pH and main problem would be bad taste ;)

Comment: @mithoron Hmm, okay. So the pH isn't high enough to where the  product with OH- exceeds the o/p product. Also isn't high enough to where enough phenols are converted to anions, and therefore the side product from that reaction is not too much either?

Comment: Coupling of diazo group with oxygen from OH or O-Ar anions is reversible at such pH. With the ring much less so.

Comment: @Mithoron Okay, so not is there a small proportion of those species (OH-, Ar-O-), but the reaction is more reversible as well. But why is that the case?

Comment: @Mithoron The reason i ask, is in the reaction O-Ar anion + Ar–N=N+ -----> Ar–N=N-O-Ar, it appears to me that the products are a lot more stable than the reactants. So I don't understand why you are saying it would be reversible at this pH, or the role of pH in the case of something like this (apart from the actual generation of the O-Ar anion)

Comment: @Mithoron My bad, I forgot to include the Cl- on the Ar–N=N+. Okay, so since it's an ion exchange reaction, it is reversible. And decerasing/increasing the anion concentrations on the reactant side through varying the pH would modulate the extent of the forward reaction. If I understand correctly, this is the reason you said that? and also that EAS isn't as easily reversible due to its mechanism.